# JavaScript comparison failing

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to prompt for, then compare two values:

```
var x,y;
x = prompt("enter the first value","");
x = prompt("enter the second value","");

if( x > y)
{
  alert("x>y");
}
else if(x < y)
{
  alert("y>x")
}
else 
{
  alert("error");
}
```

Each time I run this, the `alert("error")` line is hit. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are not assigning `y`:

```
x=prompt("enter the first value","");
x=prompt("enter the second value","");
```

Both assignments assign `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

```
x=prompt("enter the first value","");
y=prompt("enter the second value","");
```

Answer (score 0):

your second line should set y instead of x.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=prompt("enter the first value","");
x=prompt("enter the second value","");
```

should be:

```
x=prompt("enter the first value","");
y=prompt("enter the second value","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you did not intentioanlly write x= twice?

Answer (score 0):

You're prompting for and assigning `x` twice, thus `y` is left `undefined`.

Anything `undefined` will not be considered true.

```
var x,y;
x = prompt("enter the first value","");
y = prompt("enter the second value","");

if      ( x > y ) {  alert("x>y");    } 
else if ( x < y ) {  alert("y>x");    } 
else              {  alert("error");  }
```